# SVN source files location

Tags: svn, svn-administraton

My SVN server is hosted on a remote Windows 2012 Server host and my need is to have a daily backup of the SVN sources database (plain folder copy). In order to achieve this I've got to tell the administrators which folders must be backed up.

I can find svnadmin in C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin but I've got no clue about where the actual sources are located.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something only the administrator of the server can tell you.

If you connect to your repository via Apache (i.e. your repository URL starts with `http://` or `https://`), look in the Apache configuration file for the URL or your repository.  You can use the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic) as a reference, but the administrator should be looking for the `SVNPath` or `SVNParentPath` directives, e.g.:

```
<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/svn/repository
</Location>
```

If you connect to your repository via *svnserve* (i.e. your repository URL starts with `svn://` or `svn+ssh://`), then the path to the repository on disk was passed via the command line to start the process.  Your administrator should refer to [how the *svnserve* process was started](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking) to determine the path.